# chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, pygal

I'm learning python with the book: "Python Crash Course: A Hands-On, Project-Based Introduction to Programming". In chapter 17 of the book "Working with APIs", I did as the book says, but an error is occurring. I don't know what the error means. Does that mean there is something wrong with the site-packages? How to fix it?

```
import requests
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, LightenStyle as LS

# Make an API call, and store the response.
url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'
r = requests.get(url)
print("Status code:", r.status_code)

# Store API response in a variable.
response_dict = r.json()
print("Total repositories:", response_dict['total_count'])

# Explore information about the repositories.
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']

names, plot_dicts = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])

    plot_dict = {
        'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
        'label': repo_dict['description'],
        }
    plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)

# Make visualization.
my_style = LS('#333366', base_style=LCS)

my_config = pygal.Config()
my_config.x_label_rotation = 45
my_config.show_legend = False
my_config.title_font_size = 24
my_config.label_font_size = 14
my_config.major_label_font_size = 18
my_config.truncate_label = 15
my_config.show_y_guides = False
my_config.width = 1000

chart = pygal.Bar(my_config, style=my_style)
chart.title = 'Most-Starred Python Projects on GitHub'
chart.x_labels = names

chart.add('', plot_dicts)
chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
```

the error is below

```
Status code: 200
Total repositories: 2198954
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2018-07-13-1.py", line 45, in <module>
    chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pygal\graph\public.py", line 114, in render_to_file
    f.write(self.render(is_unicode=True, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pygal\graph\public.py", line 52, in render
    self.setup(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pygal\graph\base.py", line 217, in setup
    self._draw()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pygal\graph\graph.py", line 933, in _draw
    self._plot()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pygal\graph\bar.py", line 146, in _plot
    self.bar(serie)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pygal\graph\bar.py", line 116, in bar
    metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pygal\util.py", line 233, in decorate
    metadata['label'])
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pygal\_compat.py", line 61, in to_unicode
    return string.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: The error basically means that your file `python_repos.svg` doesn't contain anything

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by one of the labels you're setting on the chart being `None`, which is one of [Python's special built-in constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html).  When pygal comes to render the chart it expects the label to be a string and calls the `decode` function.  This function doesn't exist on a `None` object, so the error is raised.

Looking at the name and descriptions of the Github repositories (which you're setting as the x labels and data labels, respectively) we can see that the description for one of the repositories is `None`.  I wouldn't say there is anything particularly wrong with the code from the book, it's just bad luck that one of the most starred Python repositories *at this moment in time* has no description.

We can work around this by checking for `None` values in the for loop:

```
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:

    if repo_dict['name'] is None:
        names.append('')  # Empty string.
    else:
        names.append(repo_dict['name'])

    plot_dict = {'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count']}
    if repo_dict['description'] is not None:
        plot_dict['label'] = repo_dict['description']

    plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)
```

In the first part we've added an empty string in place of any `None` values (because you'll need something there when you set the x labels).

In the second part we've created the dict with just the value, then added the description as a label only if the description is **not** `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
H=''
names, plot_dicts = [],[]

for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
   names.append(repo_dict['name'])

   if repo_dict['description']is not None:
      H = repo_dict['description']

   plot_dict = {
        'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
        'label':H,  
            }

   plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)
```